# Unresolved dependence org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom in JBoss 7 Quickstarts

Tags: maven, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to get arquillian run with jboss 7. I have downloaded the Quickstart projects from JBoss site, at http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads, but I'm having troubles in running the Arquillian tests in the kitchensink project.

Maven is not able to find:

```
org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:pom:1.0.0.CR1
```

When I run

```
mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-managed
```

Maven allways fail to find the artifact:

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/arquillian/arquillian-bom/1.0.0.CR1/arquillian-bom-1.0.0.CR1.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:pom:1.0.0.CR1' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom

Reason: POM 'org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:pom:1.0.0.CR1

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 for project org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom
```

I'm using Maven 3, though with maven 2 the result is the same.

is Anyone running into this dependency problem?

Answer (score 1):

The dependency `org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom` dependency is available in the JBoss Maven repository. It is preferable to [add the "jboss-public" group of the JBoss Maven repository to your Maven settings.xml file](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users) so that you do not need to add this repository to every project POM.

Answer (score 1):

I have this dependency problem, too, although I've added the JBoss Maven repository like Vineet suggested.

arquillian-parent-jetty-1.0.0.CR1.pom is correctly downloaded from the JBoss repository:

```
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-parent-jetty/1.0.0.CR1/arquillian-parent-jetty-1.0.0.CR1.pom
```

But then Maven tries to download arquillian-bom from repository central, although it's available at https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/jboss/arquillian/arquillian-bom/1.0.0.CR1/arquillian-bom-1.0.0.CR1.pom

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/arquillian/arquillian-bom/1.0.0.CR1/arquillian-bom-1.0.0.CR1.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:pom:1.0.0.CR1' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

As workaround I copied the arquillian-bom-1.0.0.CR1.pom to my local repository myself but then everyone else who wants to build my project has to do that too.

Comment: Yes, I also have the JBoss Maven repository configured but still have the same problem.